# Optimize substrings anagram compare algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, string-comparison, anagram

Im trying to solve one challenge where you have to check all string substrings are they anagrams. The condition is basically For S=abba, anagramic pairs are: {S[1,1],S[4,4]}, {S[1,2],S[3,4]}, {S[2,2],S[3,3]} and {S[1,3],S[2,4]}

Problem is that I have string with 100 chars and execution time should be below 9 secs. My time is around 50 secs... Below is my code, I will appreciate any advice - if you give me only directions or pseudo code it is even better.

```
$time1 = microtime(true);
$string = 'abdcasdabvdvafsgfdsvafdsafewsrgsdcasfsdfgxccafdsgccafsdgsdcascdsfsdfsdgfadasdgsdfawdascsdsasdasgsdfs';
$arr = [];
$len = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $len - 1; $j++) {
            $push = substr($string, $i, $j);
            array_push($arr, $push);
        }
    } else {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $len - $i; $j++) {
            $push = substr($string, $i, $j);
            array_push($arr, $push);
        }
    }
}
$br = 0;
$arrLength = count($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($key === count($arr) - 1) {
        break;
    }
    for ($k = $key + 1; $k < $arrLength; $k++) {
        if (is_anagram($val, $arr[$k]) === true) {
            $br++;
        }
    }
}
    echo $br."</br>";


function is_anagram($a, $b)
{
    $result = (count_chars($a, 1) == count_chars($b, 1));
    return $result;
}
$time2 = microtime(true);
echo "Script execution time: ".($time2-$time1);
```

Edit:

Hi again, today I had some time so I tried to optimize but couldnt crack this... This is my new code but I think it got worse. Any advanced suggestions ?

```
<?php

$string = 'abdcasdabvdvafsgfdsvafdsafewsrgsdcasfsdfgxccafdsgccafsdgsdcascdsfsdfsdgfadasdgsdfawdascsdsasdasgsdfs';    
$arr = [];
$len = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $len - 1; $j++) {

            $push = substr($string, $i, $j);
            array_push($arr, $push);
        }
    } else {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $len - $i; $j++) {
            $push = substr($string, $i, $j);
            array_push($arr, $push);
        }
    }
}

$br = 0;
$arrlen = count ($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (($key === $arrlen - 1)) {
        break;
    }

    for ($k = $key + 1; $k < $arrlen; $k++) {

    $result = stringsCompare($val,$arr[$k]);
        if ($result === true)
        {
            $br++;
        }

}

    echo $br."\n";
}

function stringsCompare($a,$b)
{
    $lenOne = strlen($a);
    $lenTwo = strlen ($b);
    if ($lenOne !== $lenTwo)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $fail = 0;
        if ($lenOne === 1) {
            if ($a === $b) {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $lenOne; $x++)
        {
         $position = strpos($b,$a[$x]);
             if($position === false)
             {
                 $fail = 1;
                 break;

             }
            else
            {
                $b[$position] = 0;
                $fail = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($fail === 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
    }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to check all possible substrings vs all other (same length) substrings?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I modified the code and added a rule to break if substring which Im checking has different length from the second substring. if they are different it is obvious that they cant be anagrams but this doesnt solve the speed issues. 

@Mihai codereview.stackexchange.com would be better place for the question, thanks I will post there from now such things. Is it possible to move it ?

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of another rule that all anagrams of a certain string can meet. For example, something about the number of occurrences of each character.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I will see how much time reduce will this bring me.